# Multiple content holders in a master page

Tags: asp.net

I created a simple web application project in VS 2008. I added a master page to it. I then added two panels to it. In each panel I added a ContentPlaceHolder. To each ContentPlaceHolder I added a ContentPage.

When I run it using the Vs 2008 internal web server none of the Content holder pages are displayed. Any help? I suspect there is something I am doing fundamentally wrong.

Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="200px" Style="z-index: auto;
        left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="200px" Style="z-index: auto;
        left: 205px; top: 0px; position: absolute">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>




<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
Content Page 1
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:Content>





<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
Content Page 2
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you show us the ASPX markup for the master page and for a content page based on that master page??

Comment: The question is not usefull unless you specify markup.

Comment: everything in your code seems to be in place.  when you run the application, is it going to WebForm1.aspx or WebForm2.aspx?  or do you have it going to a different page like default.aspx?

Comment: I've tried all three and get the same results. It only ever shows a single ASP page.

Answer (score 2):

Silly question: do you have this setup??

- on your master page, you should have the two `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>` with separate ID's, e.g.

  ```
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="placeHolder1" runat="server" />
  ```

  and

  ```
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="placeHolder2" runat="server" />
  ```
- on the actual page (which is based on that master page), you should have `<asp:Content>` which references the appropriate place holder defined in the master page:

  ```
  <asp:Content id="content1" ContentPlaceholderID="placeHolder1" runat="server">
     ....
  </asp:Content>
  ```

  and

  ```
  <asp:Content id="content2" ContentPlaceholderID="placeHolder2" runat="server">
     ....
  </asp:Content>
  ```

Do you have this?? That's the way it should be, really. So you should definitely see something when you show the actual data page in the browser....

Comment: Updated the question, please check.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `runat="server"` on both your ContentPlaceHolder and Content tags.

Comment: Updated the question, please check.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="200px" Style="z-index: auto;
        left: 0px; top: 0px; position: absolute">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="200px" Style="z-index: auto;
        left: 205px; top: 0px; position: absolute">
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </asp:Panel>
    </form>
</body>
</html>




<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
Content Page 1
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
</asp:Content>





<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication5.WebForm2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">
Content Page 2
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: for updates, please edit your original question, or add a comment to your question. do not post updates as an answer.